# Is there a generic word to qualify dawn, sunrise, noon, sunset and dusk?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a generic word to qualify times of the day that are defined by physical phenomena, namely dawn, sunrise, (solar) noon, sunset and dusk?

I'm looking for a word similar to how new, full, crescent... moon are called "phases". Or how equinox refers to both to the March and the September equinox.

Edit:

Usage:

> The two instants in time when the plane of Earth's equator passes through the geometric center of the Sun's disk every year are called **equinoxes**.

> The events that occurs when the Sun appears to reach its most northerly or southerly excursion relative to the celestial equator on the celestial sphere are called **solstices**.

By analogy:

> The time when the upper rim of the Sun appears on the horizon in the morning and the time when the upper limb of the Sun disappears below the horizon are called **[insert word]**.

Comment: You should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: These phenomena aren't just about the position of the sun in the sky. They're also related to nearby geographic features: mountains will block the rising sun and cause a later sunrise.

Comment: I suspect the example sentences simply didn't make it clear where in such sentences the desired word would fall. Can you confirm: are you looking for a word that works in this blank? "Equinoxes, solstices, sunrises and sunsets are all ____s" —That is, a word *for* "terms used to identify units of or points in time by reference to celestial phenomena"?

Comment: @PoundHash in mathematics the word "extremum" means "a minimum or a maximum". It is a very convenient word. Twilight means the time before sunrise or after sunset. In my personal case, I'm creating an app that returns those times in a list, which I'm currently calling "TimesOfDay" but I'd like a more elegant word.

Comment: Is there a reason you included midday but not midnight? Is it because it's only about daytime not nighttime? Is your notion one that would include or exclude that most startling of our sun's recurring daytime events, the total eclipse?

Comment: @tchrist solar noon is a time that depends on your location on Earth. It is not 12:00 . As far as I know, midnight is defined as 24:00 , so it is not based on a physical phenomenon.

Answer (score 2):

These are [times of day](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/time_of_day).  I don't believe there's a single word for this.

The phrase *time of day* has quite a few definitions, but one of them in the OED is:

> A point or period in the course of a day or of the diurnal cycle.

And one example of its use they give is:

> 2007   D. S. Wilson *Evol. for Everyone*  Morning sickness..is better named pregnancy sickness because it can occur at any time of day.

Comment: The downside of this is that it's ambiguous. It could also refer to the numbers on the clock, (which is determined by politicians as they argue over daylight savings time).

Comment: @Laurel -named- times of day?

Answer (score 1):

No. There are some events and circumstances for which there is no English word. Yours is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

There are terms from astrology that can be used here.

Broadly speaking, the plane of the equator is divided into **houses**.  The exact number of houses depends on the astrological scheme, but 12 is a common number. The Sun ascends in one house at sunrise and descends in another house at sunset.

The “starting point” of each house is referred to as a **cusp**, and there are various ways of setting these. The points where the sun rises or sets are among them.

The ascendant house and the descendant house define regions of observation. The planets and constellations visible in those houses are supposed to have special significance in forecasting a person’s life.

This doesn’t provide a direct answer to the OP’s question. However, if there is a term that encompasses sunrises and sunsets, astrology and celestial navigation are the most likely sources.

The Wikipedia article on astrological houses is actually worth reading. It appears that the definition of the houses has a bearing on which heavenly bodies are “dominant”, which affects the forecast. There is a wide variety of definitions available, allowing forecasts to be conveniently retrofitted to align with current events .

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/House_(astrology)

Answer (score 0):

[Brittanica Dictionary's "Ask the Editor" column](https://www.britannica.com/dictionary/eb/qa/parts-of-the-day-early-morning-late-morning-etc) simply calls them *parts of the day*.

> Parts of the Day
> Morning ... Afternoon ... Evening ... Night ...

The editor was writing in response to a question about terms such as "early morning", "later morning" and so on, which correspond broadly to your terms of "dawn" and so on.

Answer (score -2):

"[Crepuscular](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crepuscular)" often refers to sunset and dusk, and it is sometimes also used to refer to dawn and sunrise. (It has a noun form, "[crepuscule](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/crepuscule)", which is more rare.) However, it doesn't refer to "phases" of the sun, so it may not be what you're looking for.

I'm not aware of any specific term that would include those times and also solar noon.